# How to source inner functions to test them in R console

Tags: r, console, scope

Is it possible to source and use inner functions from R console?

For example, I have the following functions defined in a file called `script.R`

```
outer_fun = function() {
    inner_fun = function() {
        print('inner_fun')
    }
    print('outer_fun')
}
```

sourcing `script.R` adds `outer_fun` to global environment but not `inner_fun`. But I need to access `inner_fun` to test it. So, I have to define `inner_fun` out of any function's scope. But then the organization of the code gets messy which makes maintenance hard.

Comment: Use can use `debug` to step through `outer_fun`

Comment: If the `inner_fun` is not trivial, I wouldn't define it inside `outer_fun`. However, that doesn't mean that code organization in a package automatically becomes messy.

Comment: I don't understand what is so awful about moving the definition of `inner_fun` outside `outer_fun`. Can you elaborate on why you think it is "messy"?

Comment: Publishing a package is something you should do only **after** extensive testing of each and every function.  I suggest fully debugging your "inner_fun"ctions before sticking them inside other functions (if you in fact still want to place them there).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, there are also many reasons a function can stop working without even changing its code: hardware change, R version change, dependencies versions change, etc. Hence the need to test even after your code is pushed to production (published). Where I work, unit tests are automated and running every hour.

Comment: @flodel good point. So I'll amend my comment to say "Keep all function separate in your development environment, and repackage only after full unit testing."

Comment: Thank you CarlWitthoft and @flodel for your suggestions. I think you are right. It is safer to keep functions independent. 

My rationale for putting some functions into other functions was to keep public interfaces as minimal as possible.

Comment: If public access is the main concern, then you can prefix the function name with a dot `.inner_fun` to somewhat hide it. Functions like `ls()` won't find it unless you specify `all = TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only possible way to add `inner_fun` to the global environment is to run the function body within the global environment via

```
eval(body(outer_fun))
inner_fun() # is available now
```

If `outer_fun` needs some parameters to run, you can add them to the global environment.

But I don't think that you really would need such a hack for to "test" functions if you use the debugging mode properly. Try

```
outer_fun = function() {
  browser()
  inner_fun = function() {
      print('inner_fun')
  }
  print('outer_fun')
}
```

Then the following works on the console:

```
> outer_fun()
Called from: outer_fun()
Browse[1]> inner_fun()
[1] "inner_fun"
Browse[1]>
```

Comment: `eval` is sure to pollute his environment or error out with "object unfound". `browser/debug` are very interactive functions, not very good for unit testing.